# Android XAMARIN : Camera intent is returning with null data in callback

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to use camera intent in my platform independent mobile app that I am trying to create using XAMARIN with C# as a programming language. As a starter I found this [link](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/)

Using the similar code in my application doesn't work. Specifically when control is transferred to onActivity callback function, the data parameter is always null. My question is why it is null? And how to save image and usse it my application? Sample application mentioned in this tutorial is complete in itself . I also tried to download and run the sample application as it is with no luck. :-(

My targeted API version is 10.

Below is **MENIFEST.XML** file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.gotechark.dresspal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <application android:label="Dress Pal"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

As we can see all required permissions for camera intent to work are mentioned here in. I've found many other question on stack overflow and on xamarin forums in the same respect which are either good for only java based android app,or mostly not answered or unresolved.

Comment: In my experience, there isn't much difference between the Java stuff and C# stuff when working in Android, from a conceptual point of view. I've found plenty of solutions to C#/Xamarin problems by investigating Java code. I can't answer your question, but for future reference, don't immediately dismiss a potential solution to your problem because it's not C#/Xamarin.

Comment: I definitely agree with DaveDev, not only can you easily convert majority of java code, the syntax is very similar as well. Maybe try taking an existing java-android sample and rewriting it within C#?

Comment: Agreed to both.After reading your response I tried implementing java  android sample given in [link]http://blog.vogella.com/2011/09/13/android-how-to-get-an-image-via-an-intent/ and tried implementing it in C#/xamarin. By using similar code and help of VS2013 this was way too easier to implement, this one worked flawlessly.But when I tried the same way with camera intent it didn't actually worked.I first implemented sample camera app using java.Where I was able to retrieve response through data parameter in OnActivityResult() method.Everything was so smooth but not in case of C#/Xamarin code.

Comment: It's possible your activity is losing state in between getting to the camera and coming back to your code.  Try overriding OnSavedStateInstance and making sure to store the path to your image so your activity has access to it when you return.  Read about saved state [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing your code I cannot be sure this will help you, but notice in the example you linked to, they never use the data parameter that is returned from the Camera activity. Instead, before calling the Camera activity (in the *TakeAPicture* function), they pass along some extra data in the intent, telling the Camera activity to store the image in a file:

```
intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(_file));
```

Then, when the Camera activity returns, the image is accessed using the **_file** path, not the **data** parameter.

If instead you call the Camera activity without the call to **intent.PutExtra...**, I believe you'll find the **data** parameter will be filled in with the Camera image and not null any longer, but note that it will most likely be a scaled-down image. The technique used in the link (specifying a file), will instruct the Camera activity to save the full-sized image in the specified file. But again this is just a guess.

Comment: Hi @Steven ,your suggetion helped me move little further.I tried that and was able to get well-constructed data object but again in order to receive image url I called data.Data property which was null and no url found to retrive image location.Finally I was able to make it working by declaring _file parameter as a static variable.Not sure how appropriate this workaround/solution is but worked in my case.

Comment: With all due respect @Sagar, I'm not sure you're understanding me. There will only be a "url found to retrieve image location" if you **tell** the Camera activity to save the image. How do you do this? This line does it: `intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(_file));` If you comment that line out and re-run your app, I will almost guarantee you that the data parameter returned in the OnActivityResult function will contain the scaled-down image. To get the image, you will use something like this: `Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data")`. Hope this explains better.